# TSQL show blog archive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show archive (by month and year) of articles on my blog and i cant figure out how to write sql select command.

I have table `Articles` and there is column `PublishDate` (it is datetime type) and I have to select unique `PublishDate` for this table but only for month and year.

For example if I have 3 post in september 2013 then september 2013 will be shown only once.

Result should be like this:

```
September 2013
Novermber 2013
January 2012
etc.
```

Can someone help me with this TSQL select command?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Answer (score 2):

You can form the date that you want by using SQL Server date functions:

```
select distinct datename(mm, PublishDate)+' '+cast(year(PublishDate) as varchar(255))
from Articles a
```

Because you presumably want these ordered by date, use `group by` instead:

```
select datename(mm, PublishDate)+' '+cast(year(PublishDate) as varchar(255))
from Articles a
group by datename(mm, PublishDate)+' '+cast(year(PublishDate) as varchar(255))
order by max(PublishDate) desc;
```

Comment: Great and how can i get more columns like [ArticleName]?

Comment: @Earlgray . . . You can use the second form of the query with aggregations like `min(ArticleName)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT a.*,
           DATENAME(month, PublishDate) AS MonthPublished, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(PublishDate),MONTH(PublishDate) 
                               ORDER BY  PublishDate ASC)
   FROM dbo.Articles a
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

This selects just the first (according to `PublishDate`) record for each year-month group.
Use [`DATENAME(month, PublishDate)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx?ppud=4) to get the name of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @GordonLinoff, I came up with this query that returns the name of the month along with the number of articles, and the month/year numbers:

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, PublishDate)+' '+CAST(YEAR(PublishDate) as varchar(255)) AS [monthName], MONTH(PublishDate) AS [month], YEAR(PublishDate) AS [year], COUNT(PublishDate) AS [count]
FROM Articles
WHERE status > 0
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, PublishDate)+' '+CAST(YEAR(PublishDate) as varchar(255)), MONTH(PublishDate), YEAR(PublishDate)
ORDER BY MAX(PublishDate) DESC;
```